# How would I go about rigging this model?

Tags: rigging, unreal-engine

[image: Mech with Rig]

Hey all! I'm trying to rig this mecha for Unreal Engine 4, and I have modelled it (In separate parts)and was wondering how to parent it properly for Unreal Engine 4. If I rig it mechanically as separate parts, UE4 imports the FBX as different Skeletal Meshes. I do not want this. I want it all as one mesh. But if I join it, it bends and warps, not how I want it to

Can anyone offer any advice? I want it to move mechanically but as one mesh

Answer (score 2):

You certainly can join all the separate parts into one mesh, and still have it rigged properly.

Just make sure all vertices in the vertex groups all have a weight of either one or zero. you don't want any blending (like if you painted the weights in weight paint mode.)

Join all the pieces into one object, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>J</kbd>
(If you do not already have all the bones) add an armature and place the bones accordingly.

Now select the object then the armature, so the armature is the [active object](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/21050/2217), and press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>P</kbd> > *Empty Groups*.

Go into edit mode and select a piece (<kbd>L</kbd> and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>L</kbd> should be very helpful here) make sure you are working on the correct vertex group *(naming your bones would of helped)* and set the weight to 1, then press *Assign*.
[image: edit mode assigning vertex groups for the armature]

So in that picture I am "connecting" the bone named "*Bone*" to the selected cube.
All four cubes are in the same object, but with the weights correct the pieces move independently.

If you enter *Weight Paint* mode you should only see red and blue (or black if you have [restrict](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/15080/2217) turned on). Any other colors, light blue to green means there are other values and thus a bone is going to affect part of something that you do not want it to.
[image: animated gif showing weight paint mode]